# SSLCertVerificationError while running dash code

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, plotly-dash

I am working on developing an evaluation method for digital offline games. For analysis I am using python and I want to display findings on a dashboard for which I started with DASH.
However, while running the code given in dash documents in my jupyter notebook without an internet connection I am getting the following error:

> urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)

With internet connection it is working excellent.

I have tried the following after going through some questions here but these seem to be of no help right now.

```
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
```

and

```
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
urllib.urlopen("https://no-valid-cert", context=context)
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: python for both analysis and dashboard.